# Identify duplicates based on multiple columns and parent row

Tags: sql-server

This is an example of table data that I am working on (the table contained a lot of columns, I am showing here only the relevant ones):

| Id | job_number | status | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 42FWD-42 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 42FWD-42 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 42FWD-42 | 5 | 1 |

`Id` is auto generated. `parent_id` links the job using the `id`.

When a new job is created via the app, a new row is created (with status "0"). The auto-generated `Id` is then used for subsequent rows of same job, and set as parent id.

Another record with status "1" (which is code for started) is also created just after parent record.

Explanation of the problem: due to a bug in the app, there are duplicate set of rows for the same job.

Example of problem

| Id | job_number | status | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 42FWD-42 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 42FWD-42 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 42FWD-42 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 42FWD-42 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 42FWD-42 | 5 | 1 |

As you can see from this example, due to the bug, there are 2 rows  with "0" status for the same job, and 2 rows with "1" status.

This creates a lot of problems in operation in app where the job is updated using the job number.

The status number should not repeat for a specific job.

What I want to do is to find all duplicates like those in example. For example, I want a query where I can find all duplicates which have same job number, but different parent_id and NO "5" status.

Example result using the example table above, I need the query to return:

| Id | job_number | status | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 42FWD-42 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 42FWD-42 | 1 | 2 |

Explanation of this result:

1. Row with `Id=1` is considered the correct record because it has an associated record with status "5"
2. Row with `Id=2` is considered duplicate and its associated records are also considered duplicate

Another possible case: there are duplicate rows, but none have status=5. These rows can be discarded, ie need not be shown in results.

A brief explanation of how the query works will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I forgo to add an important information:
`job_number` is case sensitive.

ie: 42**FWD**-42 and 42**fwd**-42 are different and valid job number. They should not be considered duplicates, and are 2 separate jobs.

The reason for this is the actual job number is not small text as in my example. It is a long string like a guid.

Comment: This is not only a bug in the application, it's also a bug in your database design. Whenever you're using a surrogate key, you need to ensure data integrity with constraints (unique, not null) of your natural key. If a table has no natural key, or you can't identify one, odds are you're doing it wrong.

Comment: `select * from (select *, row_number() over(partition by job_number,status order by id) as rn from tableX) as t where rn >= 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I must mention you should block identical rows by means of a `unique constraint`. I suggest that once you have eliminated all duplicates you put up a such a constraint to keep this from happening again.

Now for your question, you can do this by grouping on the duplicate columns, and have only those that count more than one.
Here is an example

```
declare @t table (id int, job_number varchar(10), status int, parent_id int)
insert into @t
values (1, '42FWD-42', 0, 0), (2, '42FWD-42', 0, 0), (3, '42FWD-42', 1, 1), (4, '42FWD-42', 1, 2), (5, '42FWD-42', 5, 1)

select max(t.id) as id, t.job_number, t.status 
from   @t t
group by t.job_number, t.status
having count(*) > 1
```

the result is

```
id  job_number  status
2   42FWD-42    0
4   42FWD-42    1
```

and to get also the parent_id you can add a self join

```
select max(t.id) as id, 
       t.job_number, 
       t.status,
       (select t2.parent_id from @t t2 where t2.id = max(t.id)) as parent_id  
from   @t t
group by t.job_number, t.status
having count(*) > 1
```

this returns

```
id  job_number  status parent_id
2   42FWD-42    0      0
4   42FWD-42    1      2
```

**EDIT**

To solve the addional problem in the edit of your question, about the case sensitive, you can fix that by using a `COLLATE` in your field retrieval and your comparision

this should do it

```
declare @t table (id int, job_number varchar(10), status int, parent_id int)
insert into @t
values (1, '42FWD-42', 0, 0), 
       (2, '42FWD-42', 0, 0), 
       (3, '42FWD-42', 1, 1), 
       (4, '42fwd-42', 1, 2), -- LOWERCASE !!!
       (5, '42FWD-42', 5, 1)

select max(t.id) as id, 
       t.job_number COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, 
       t.status,
       (select t2.parent_id from @t t2 where t2.id = max(t.id)) as parent_id  
from   @t t
group by t.job_number COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, t.status
having count(*) > 1
```

and now the result will be

```
id  job_number  status parent_id
2   42FWD-42    0      0
```

**Yet another edit**

Now, suppose you need to use the result of these duplicate `id's` in another query, you could do something like this

```
select t.* 
from  @t t
where t.id in ( select max(t.id) as id 
                from   @t t
                group by t.job_number COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, t.status
                having count(*) > 1
              )
```

What I am doing here is getting only the duplicate id's in a form that can be used to feed a where clause in another query.
This way you can use the result set in any way you wish.
Also note that for this we don't need the self join to retrieve the parent_id anymore.

One possible use of this could be to delete duplicate rows, you can write

```
delete from yourtable
where id in ( select max(t.id) as id 
                from   @t t
                group by t.job_number COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, t.status
                having count(*) > 1
            )
```

Comment: I did not add one important information in my question. "job_number" is case sensitive. How can I modify this query to account for that?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to get duplicate row data and its `id` by `job_number`, then using cte recursive to find all error records by this `id`

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY job_number ORDER BY Id) rn 
   FROM T
   WHERE status = 0
), CTE1 AS (
  SELECT id,job_number,status,parent_id
  FROM CTE
  WHERE rn > 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.id,t.job_number,t.status,t.parent_id
  FROM CTE1 c INNER JOIN T t
  ON c.id = t.parent_id 
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f4192/15/0)**:

```
| id | job_number | status | parent_id |
|----|------------|--------|-----------|
|  2 |   42FWD-42 |      0 |         0 |
|  4 |   42FWD-42 |      1 |         2 |
```